# AVLoadingIndicatorView Library not visible in app

Tags: android

added the library for showing loading effects but it is not visible or any effect is not seen. Although no error occurs but there is no effect seen when the network call begins. The show method doesnot have any effect. Currently im using using android version 4.1.2.

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/signin_back_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp"></ImageView>
        </FrameLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_signIn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:text="@string/sign_in"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18dp"></TextView>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Sign in to TruePay"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_layout_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/signin_email_address"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:hint="Username"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"></EditText>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_layout_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/signin_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:hint="@string/signin_password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"></EditText>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/forgot_password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/forgot_password"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/use_device_code"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/device_code"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <com.wang.avi.AVLoadingIndicatorView
            android:id="@+id/avi"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:indicatorName="BallPulseIndicator" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

java code

```
public class SignIn extends BaseSupportFragment {
    private View view;
    private ImageView backPage;
    private TextView signInBtn;
    private TextView forgotPassword;
    private TextView deviiceCodes;
    TextInputLayout emailLayout,passwordLayout;
    EditText email,password;
    private static SessionManagement sessionManagement;
    AVLoadingIndicatorView avi;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sign_in_fragment, container, false);
        initiateUI();
        setListener();
        return view;
    }

    public  void getTokenFromServer()
    {
        WeakHashMap<String, String> param = new WeakHashMap<>();
        param.put("username",email.getText().toString());
        param.put("password",password.getText().toString());
        Log.e("param...", String.valueOf(param));

        RetrofitInterface apiService = RetrofitClient.getClient().create(RetrofitInterface.class);
        Observable<TokenModel> call = apiService.postFishDetails(param)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
        call.subscribe(new Observer<TokenModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                //handle error
                Log.e("access",e.toString());
                try {
                    if (e instanceof HttpException) {
                        if (((HttpException) e).code() == 401) {
                            // GlobalBus.getBus().post(new TokenExpirationNotification("Token Expired"));
                        }
                    }
                    if (e instanceof IOException) {

                    }

                } catch (Exception e1) {

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(TokenModel response)
            {

                Constant.ACCESS_TOKEN = "Bearer" + response.getAccessToken();

                avi.hide();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DrawerAct.class);
                getActivity().startActivity(intent);
                getActivity().finish();


            }

        });

    }
    private void requestFocus(View view) {
        if (view.requestFocus()) {
            getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
        }
    }


    private void setListener() {
        backPage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            }
        });
        signInBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email.getText().toString()))
                {
                    emailLayout.setError("Enter Username");
                    requestFocus(email);
                }
                else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password.getText().toString()))
                {
                    passwordLayout.setError("Enter Password");
                    requestFocus(password);
                }
                else
                {

                    avi.show();
                    getTokenFromServer();
                }

            }
        });

        forgotPassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                replaceFragment(R.id.frame_layout, new ForgotPassword());
            }
        });

        deviiceCodes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                replaceFragment(R.id.frame_layout, new DeviceCode());
            }
        });
    }

    private void initiateUI()
    {

        backPage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.signin_back_button);
        signInBtn = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_signIn);
        forgotPassword = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.forgot_password);
        deviiceCodes = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.use_device_code);

        emailLayout=(TextInputLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.input_layout_email);
        passwordLayout=(TextInputLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.input_layout_password);

        email=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.signin_email_address);
        password=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.signin_password);

        avi=(AVLoadingIndicatorView)view.findViewById(R.id.avi);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Resolved the issue. Forgot to mention the indiacator color which is white by default so the loader was actually working but wasnt visible;

XML code

```
<com.wang.avi.AVLoadingIndicatorView
        android:id="@+id/avi"
        style="@style/AVLoadingIndicatorView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:indicatorColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:indicatorName="LineSpinFadeLoaderIndicator" />
```

Comment: you nailed it buddy :)

Answer (score 0):

Your parent layout is `LinearLayout`, try wrapping your main layout with a `RelativeLayout` and put the `AVLoadingIndicatorView` outside the `LinearLayout`

Answer (score 0):

Just add

`app:indicatorColor="@color/grovery_blue"` - set your color here

that's all. Enjoy your coding...